# Undefined Index - even with isset

Tags: php

Here are two lines of code that clearly have isset used in each one:

```
 $regs_text_message=(isset($this->regs_text_message) ? $this->regs_text_message: "");

 $user_text_message=((isset($regs_text_message) && $regs_text_message>"") ? $regs_text_message : $rows['regs_text_message']);
```

But I keep getting this PHP notice (for the 2nd line):

```
 PHP Notice:  Undefined index: regs_text_message
```

Does anybody know what is going on here and how to stop getting these PHP notices?

Thanks

Comment: just because an array exists doesn't mean a particular KEY in that array exists. you need to `isset($regs_text_message['regs_text_message'])`

Comment: even if regs_text_message isn't an array?

Comment: You seem to use `$rows['regs_text_message']` without checking whether the index exists.

Comment: woops, sorry, $rows['reg_text_message'];

Comment: oh..I see, so the notice is about the $rows array...got it...thanks